# Groupby and keep only groups that do contain element in a list

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df such as:

```
Groups COL1
G1 SP1-3
G1 SP2s
G1 SP4_09
G1 SP7z
G3 SP1_OK
G3 SP1-9
G4 SP1_3
G4 SP2_3
G5 SP3_5
```

I can subset only groups that do contain all the strings in COL1 present in the `list=c('SP1','SP2')`

Here I should get :

```
Groups COL1
G1 S1-3
G1 SP2s
G1 SP4_09
G1 SP7z
G4 SP1_3
G4 SP2_3
```

I keep only `G1` and `G4` because they have strings that contains `SP1` and `SP2`. The other do not contain both

data

```
structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("G1", "G3", "G4", "G5"), class = "factor"), 
    COL1 = structure(c(3L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("SP1_3", 
    "SP1_OK", "SP1-3", "SP1-9", "SP2_3", "SP2s", "SP3_5", "SP4_09", 
    "SP7z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach below should work.

```r
library(dplyr)

library(stringr)

data <- structure(list(Groups = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L),
                                          .Label = c("G1", "G3", "G4", "G5"),
                                          class = "factor"), 
                       COL1 = structure(c(3L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L),
                                        .Label = c("SP1_3", "SP1_OK", "SP1-3",
                                                   "SP1-9", "SP2_3", "SP2s", "SP3_5",
                                                   "SP4_09", "SP7z"),
                                        class = "factor")),
                  class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c(NA, -9L))


data %>% 
  group_by(Groups) %>% 
  filter(as.logical(any(str_detect(COL1, "SP1")) &
                    any(str_detect(COL1, "SP2"))))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   Groups [2]
#>   Groups COL1  
#>   <fct>  <fct> 
#> 1 G1     SP1-3 
#> 2 G1     SP2s  
#> 3 G1     SP4_09
#> 4 G1     SP7z  
#> 5 G4     SP1_3 
#> 6 G4     SP2_3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: instead of `max` you could perhaps use `any` to make it more clear?

Comment: Good idea! I usually use `max` for numeric expressions, it works for logical expressions too, but you are totally correct, `any` is easier to understand.